# extending Widget, passing Parameter?

Tags: java, gwt, extend

I extended a Widget, but how can i pass constructor vars to it :

```
    public class MenuBarNav extends MenuBar{

      public MenuBarNav() {
            this(true);

      }

    public MenuBarNav(boolean b) {


    }   

}
```

and then ;

```
MenuBarNav ksw = new MenuBarNav(true);
```

Normaly it is :

```
MenuBar test = new MenuBar(true);
```

and it shows me the Menu vertical.

do i have to extend it as Composite `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't extend widgets and should instead compose widgets (within a `Composite`).

In your specific case of why it doesn't work and how to make it work, Java 101:

```
public MenuBarNav(boolean b) {
  super(b);
}
```

Comment: I was just few seconds late than you.